# why are there 2 quotes around Session.keys in chrome console

Tags: javascript, meteor

[image: 2 quotes around Seesion.keys]

look at

```
Session.keys.selected_player
```

Is it even a valid String? Just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the values in the Session are stored as [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) strings, so the string you're storing has been passed to the `EJSON.stringify` function, which returns a string containing your string. It may make more sense to you if try passing the object `{test: "test"}` to `EJSON.stringify` and study the return value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid string.

`Session` is an instance of `IdMap` - Meteor's dictionary class which allows you to use strings, numbers and other EJSONable data as a key. It is not easy to do with plain JS objects as some strings are special properties (like `__proto__` or `prototype`), numbers are converted to strings, etc.